# Magento - Product like category

Tags: magento

I found this website and I would like to know witch type of product use for a similar project

http://www.bonpoint.com/it/h14look1b.html

There is a simple product but non salable with associated product

Any suggetsions

Thanks

Comment: What do yo mean with which type of product? Is not clear what need to be answered.

Comment: If is created like a simple_product or different type

Comment: If I create a simple product with associated, I must have a price in this case there is no price for the product

Comment: It looks like it might be either a `bundle` or `grouped` product.

Comment: in bundle there are the option for the bundle and in a grouped you have to set a price for the group.

Comment: Maybe managed by a CSS class?

Comment: Is possibile add a class in list or grid for the product with a particolar attribute?